# Are table cellspacing and cellpadding always 0 (EVEN IF EXPLICTILY SET) if in strict mode?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, strict, quirks-mode

I have a page I'm converting from quirks mode to strict mode.  I added this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"    
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/DTD/strict.dtd">
```

All of a sudden all my tables collapsed that use cellpadding and cellspacing.  The page looks fine in IE7 but has collapsed in Firefox.  Is this expected?

By using strict mode, even if I set `cellpadding=10` it will render as 0? (no padding)?

Do I need to convert all the table cells to `divs`?

Comment: Not sure if it would work, but did you try using css? Something like `td { padding: 10px; }` might work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you write "cellpadding=10" or "cellpadding=10px" ?

Answer (score 0):

That's not something that should happen generally.  Might there be some markup that's getting interpreted differently?  Did you try validating the HTML?